# Solutions for Google Script Editor error Code.gs:3

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a function that finds the price of a stock when any given date is entered.

```js
onEdit(e) { 

    var row = e.range.getRow()

    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange( row,4).setValue(new Date())
```

I just want to understand what I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks!

*I originally had :'s ending each that also caused 'token' errors.

Comment: Obviously this isn't the entire code. This is just the part that keeps returning the error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(new Date());
}
```

And what is does is that if I type into any cell, the code inserts today's date in column D of the same row.

Is that what you want it to do?